# Implementing Revisioning with SCD2/4

Tags: sql, postgresql, dimensional-modeling, scd, scd2

I'm working on a project that is a sort of bill of materials manager that needs to support revisioning of components.  After some research, I've stumbled upon slowly changing dimensions type 2 and type 4 which seems like the most appropriate pattern in this use cases.

However, I'm a little bit confused on a couple of concepts:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name  TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE components (
  id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name         TEXT,
  project_id   INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT fk_project FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects (id)
)
```

If I wanted to implement SCD Type 2, would the components table have the additional columns for `start_date`, `end_date`, `active`?  Or, would Type 2 be adding a `revisions` table with the same structure as `components` with the additional columns and Type 4 having a `revisions` table and a `revisions_history` table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your tables seem to be relevant to an OLTP system and SCD is a mechanism used in Kimball-style OLAP systems - so would not be relevant to what you are doing.

Are you trying to track different components associated to a project over time or are you trying to track changes to individual project or component records?

Comment: @NickW It would be both, the components can be a hierarchy (so just an additional parent_id on the components table), but I would need to track individual records (the data like component name, qunaity, etc) and how they changed, as well as if a component was added/deleted in a project. So basically a snapshot of what the state of the project looked like at a specific point in time.  And then being able to say "at s specific point in time, `component_1` looked like this, and having the ability to rollback to that version

Answer (score 0):

You can use `temporal_tables`

> System-period data versioning (also known as transaction time or
> system time) allows you to specify that old rows are archived into
> another table (that is called the history table).

https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/